# ImageView Padding attribute not displaying Properly in JellyBean

Tags: android, imageview

I have same xml code but when I am running it in Lolipop the padding attribute is working fine but in JellyBean its not working also *In my ImageView I am using an oval from drawable that is set with background attribute and transparent wifi image that has set by src attribute*

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_circle_primary"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_info_black_48dp" />
```

Here the screenshot from both version

[image]

Comment: Have you placed different resolutions of your image in drawable folders(mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi ) ?

Comment: No i have a single Image format that is 48 by 48 pixel

Comment: Thats why. Different phones have different resolutions and your image will be distorted or not look good on another resolutions. Create all the versions of your image and then check.

Comment: well ImageView will scale it or shrink image to the proper dimension of ImageView and I agree the result will be distorted in some phone but specifying padding in lolipop means Image will be of size whatever is left after padding but in jelly bean its not

Comment: In what drawable folder did you put ic_info_black_48dp?

Comment: I am using Android Studio and there is only One folder "Drawable" I just put it there

Comment: It is only a view over the folders. Check on your filesystem or change view in your Project tab from "Android" to something like "Project".

Comment: I changed it and I checked in my c drive where actual files are present there is only one drawable folder no drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi etc, Let me check with different version of Image

Comment: You should move it to drawable-mdpi, so proper scaling is carried out. Anyway, I just noticed your image seems too big: you have 42- 8*2 = 26dp space but your image (after you move to mdpi) will be 48dp... If you move it to xhdpi it will be 24dp, so it will look "alright", but I don't know whether it is what you intend.

Comment: And btw you can check its bounds activating Developer Options > Drawing > Show layout bounds

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83681/discussion-between-l-x-and-gil).

Comment: you can add  this code :   ```android:scaleType="centerInside" ``` in your ImageView , it work for me ~

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the `ImageView` inside of a `FrameLayout` and put the `android:padding="8dp"` and the `android:background="@drawable/icon_circle_primary"` attributes to the `FrameLayout`.

Something like:

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="50"
android:background="@drawable/icon_circle_primary"
android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_info_black_48dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: +one for you amazing answer , Its a hack but work  but I still don't understand why I am getting different views regarding different phones/Version

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this will help someone, I had a problem where the ImageView padding was not working for me where I also had `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` set.

Adding `android:cropToPadding="true"` did it for me.